# Exlude a file from a directory listing

Tags: file, directory, python-3.4, windows-xp-sp3

I tested  this [program](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/downloads/watch_directory.py), it checks a directory if a file is deleted, renamed or modified.  I wonder how can I check a direcory by exluding certain files ? How can I modify the variable
`PATH_TO_WATCH = ["C:/myDirectory"]` so that the program probes `C:/myDirectory` but excludes 2 files from checking (file1.txt and file2.txt) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code must be replace.

```
for action, file in results:
  full_filename = os.path.join (path_to_watch, file)
  if not os.path.exists (full_filename):
    file_type = "<deleted>"
  elif os.path.isdir (full_filename):
    file_type = 'folder'
  else:
    file_type = 'file'
  yield (file_type, full_filename, ACTIONS.get (action, "Unknown"))
```

By this code:

```
for action, file in results:
  if (file != 'file1.txt' and file != 'file2.txt'): #here you cut the check of the files you don't want.
    full_filename = os.path.join (path_to_watch, file)
    if not os.path.exists (full_filename):
      file_type = "<deleted>"
    elif os.path.isdir (full_filename):
      file_type = 'folder'
    else:
      file_type = 'file'
    yield (file_type, full_filename, ACTIONS.get (action, "Unknown"))
```